# Can be two identical socket established?

Tags: sockets

A socket is combination of an IP address, a transport protocol and a port number.
For example: two hosts, on different LANs behind NAT, can have the same IP (let's say 192.168.0.2).
When these hosts connect to a web server, could two identical sockets be established?
I know that ports are randomly generated, but on different hosts it could be generated the same one.
Or it is server which tells that this port number is already in use?
Or is it NAT device, which changing SRC IP in IP packet?
How does NAT device knows then, where to send packet back to host on LAN?

Thanks

Comment: _"behind NAT"_ - so they'll have their public IP as source IP, not their LAN IP.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly guessed it is NAT who assigns ephemeral port number, so they can't coincide. Therefore, from server perspective, destination duplet of host #1 would be something like 192.168.0.2:46812, and for host #2 - 192.168.0.2:51378. When NAT receives these packets, it knows which host behind the NAT the packet belongs to based on the port number. If you have access to machine's console you can check the numbers with `netstat -anp`

Comment: So all job does NAT, reencapsulating SRC IP address and port number. Thanks guys for help :)

Comment: and yes, small correction - 192.168.0.2 would have to be NAT's address. I also wouldn't use "encapsulation" here, it is more like IP header rewriting.